# How to return a string in same view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying return a string from controller to the same view in MVC

but its returning to a new view

Below is the code of my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index2", "home", FormMethod.Post))
{

<label></label>    
 <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
}
```

Below is the code of my controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        string _return = "Hello world";
        return Content(_return);

    }
```

how can I display "hello world" in the label

thanks.....

Comment: Looks like Razor syntax for ASP.NET MVC with c# code. Please note that the `model-view-controler` tag specifically states to use `asp.net-mvc` tag for ASP.NET MVC questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can pass the value using Model objects or simply use ViewBag

public ActionResult Index2()
{
    ViewBag.return = "Hello world";
    return View("YourViewName");

}
```

> In View

```
<label>@ViewBag.return</label>
```

Comment: thank you for your response ....how to this after clicking button.one question : how do i return partial view in the same view after clicking button  can u pls give me examples

Comment: You can refer this for example http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: its will return in new view but i want in same view

Comment: Partial view is nothing but a part of your view/page. It loads in same view. Above link is just an example to load PV.

Comment: thank you ...can u address me for tutorial with coding

Comment: You can find many sample projects over net. You can download and see how it works http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698246/ASP-NET-MVC-Special-Views-Partial-View-and-Layout

Answer (score 1):

Make the model type of your view `string` like this:

```
@model string
```

And use that string in your code like this:

```
The action told me to say @Model
```

Another way, if you want to display the content of an action method is to call `Html.Action` in your view:

```
@Html.Action("Index2")
```

Comment: i have tried your code but still its showing in new view....@Html.Action("Index2") is showing before clicking button ....where i making error...